# Express creates different session when auth header is changed

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js, express-session

I am new to express and I am trying to create session when user logs in to my app.I am using passport for authentication. To login user I am creating basic strategy and on success of basic strategy I am creating a JWT token which I am storing at client side in cookie and I use JWT strategy for subsequent requests.

But I notice that express-session is creating one session when I am logging in which has Basic header and another session for subsequent calls which has JWT header.

Here is my code where I am saving session on login

```
signin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('basic', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({ error: 'message' });
        }
        var token = jwt.encode({ user: user}, config.db.secret);
        res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true, path: '\/', Secure: true });
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, firstName: user.firstName });
        delete user.password;
        req.session.user = user;
        req.session.save();
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

But when I debug this code it shows one sessionID in req.sessionID and it show different sessionID in req.sessionID in the following code which as JWT authentication

```
listProducts = function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    //here req.session.user is undefined which I have saved at login. and sessionID is also different
    res.json({ demo: 'response' });
};
```

I am expecting it to be same sessionID throughout the life cycle till user logs out of my app.
Why is this exactly happening? What is the solution to it?

Comment: Can you add the code where you add express-session and passport middlewares to your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the response before saving the session.

Try saving the session, then sending the response instead.

`express-session` modifies `res.end` to make it perform `express-session` specific tasks introducing the sequential coupling you were victim of: https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/index.js#L249

Comment: I tries it.but no luck.

Comment: `session.save` is **asynchronous**, meaning it takes a callback. Place the response sending code inside the callback. e.g: `req.session.save(function (err) { if (err) { return next(err); } res.status(200).json(...) });`

Comment: still No. As far as I understand passport.session and express.sesssion should handle it on their own. But somehow its not working in my case.

Comment: Then debug the problem by looking at the content of the cookies being sent with each response using your browser developer tools.

Comment: What should it contain? I can see connect.sid and token cookie which is my JWT token. I guess connect.sid is for session.

Comment: The value for `connect.sid` should be preserved across the session. Try using an incognito tab so no old cookies kick in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144159/discussion-between-nikhil-mehta-and-partycoder).

Comment: the cookie is being preserved.

Comment: it worked. I do not know what was the issue. I just stopped my node server and started. Earlier I was just restarting it from VS code. Thanks @partycoder